# Is it possible to use SQL XML to insert, and get output from each record?

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I would like to perform a SQL XML insert (on MSSQL), and in this case I need to insert a list of files into the DB (this is simple enough). However, there's an auto generated PK column (ID), and I need the ID for each newly created filename without performing a 2nd query. Is this possible? I guess it doesn't matter if the result is/isn't XML, but the input certainly has to be.

Comment: do you mean you want to store an XML string in a data base?

Comment: How is this being done - via managed code, BCP, or something else? Are you loading your files serially?

Comment: @nbolton oh well that clears things up then! Now I know exactly what your problem is, ergo, exactly how to help you. Yes I am being an arse here. But Clearly, if someone asks for some clarification on your question responding with one word is bound to fill in all the blanks.

Comment: @thecoshman Sorry my response was rather terse, I must have been having a bad day. I assumed you were asking me if I wanted to insert an XML string into 1 column of 1 row, which is rather trivial in comparison to what I need to achieve ;-) -- To clarify, say I have XML <fl><f>a</f><f>b</f></fl>, I need to into a table with 2 columns, where the "filename" column has values "a" in the 1st row and "b" in the 2nd. I then need to return the auto generated IDs (from the 1st column) as a normal SQL result.

Comment: Reading your question again... it seems all you are trying to do is perform an SQL query that inserts data into a table, utilises the primary key of the row for each record you enter, but then also returns a set of data. Though I have never tried it my self, I am almost certain you can insert multiple rows of data. How ever, I am sure that SQL is one direction at a time, you can read OR write. You can query for 'affected' rows, but I have no idea how well that goes down performance wise.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure your assertion about direction is correct. If you use a stored procedure, then you can both insert and select in one command.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question... I think a possible solution (as one transaction) would be to do a SQL-XML insert as normal. Then, select all rows in the table, and left join against the data in the "to insert" XML data, where the join column is filename... This should return the IDs for all rows that have just been inserted.